# Is a laboratory space a (decent enough) inertial system?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, inertial-frames, estimation

regarding a 1m x 1m x 1m space (e.g. at LIGO) and a particle (e.g. a proton) moving at $0,96\cdot c$ I was wondering if this space could be treated as an inertial system.

I calculated that from one side to the other a proton would require $3,475\cdot 10^{-9}$ seconds dropping off in height as far as $5,922\cdot 10^{-17}$ m, which is about $6$% of an atomic diameter. Would you consider this effect to be insignificant?

Comment: Decent enough *for what*? Insignificant compared to what other effects? Whether any approximation is adequate depends on what you are using it for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Or no.

It depends on what experiment you're doing, what you're trying to measure, and how precisely.

For many experiments, the precision is low enough that many laboratory spaces can be considered to be inertial systems, fully describable by special relativity, and general relativity can safely be completely ignored.

On the other hand, if you're doing a measurement that is precise enough (such comparing as high-precision optical clocks at different heights, or indeed the LIGO measurements themselves) then you do need general relativity.

As a general rule, "insignificant" is a meaningless word without context.

Comment: Thank you for this precise answer! So why would (e.g. at LIGO or CERN) one consider laboratory spaces not to be an inertial system? In what way does the measurement need to be this exact? Because of where the new particles resulting from the impact are located?